# 302 Moved Temporarily, BUT when I open it on the browser directly it's ok

Tags: http-status-code-302

I put a script tag on my html page, and run it on firefox, firebug tell me that the script is '302 Moved Temporarily',
but when I open that script in new tag on the browser, it's 200 ok(response conrrectly)~~

I saw that when 302 the server response a redirect page, here's the header:

```
Cache-Control   max-age=2592000
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  154
Content-Type    text/html
Date    Tue, 26 Mar 2013 08:10:33 GMT
Expires Thu, 25 Apr 2013 08:10:33 GMT
Location    http://www.xxxx.com/error/index.html
Server  nginx
```

if I put the script on other server(no error redirecting page settings), will not come across this question

Anyone met the same question with me?
I don't want to put the file on other server and have no permission to config this server. 
Is there a solution to this?

Thanks a lot and forgive my poor English.